# what's wrong with my database? what should i do?

Tags: mysql, security, web, risk-analysis

Till yesterday, my database had only one table called `id1753536_local`.
today when I looked at my `databases` I found another table named `information_schema`

what does it mean? I have performed several sql injection attacks on websites and they all contained a table called `information_schema.` so is my site also vulnerable to sql injection? or it is usual?

Comment: Uhm… really?! https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html

Comment: I am running this site from 2 months and today this table came itself

Comment: It's always been there. Why you just see it now is anyone's guess.

Comment: so its not because of any vulneribility

Comment: Have you read the link provided by deceze?

Comment: yes, I have read

Comment: Also please review the definition of "database" versus "table".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incase you still have questions, here is the take away from what @deceze 's posted to answer your question.

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is a database within each MySQL instance, the place that stores information about all the other databases that the MySQL server maintains. The `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database contains several read-only tables. They are actually views, not base tables, so there are no files associated with them, and you cannot set triggers on them. Also, there is no database directory with that name.

And regarding if it is a vulnerability, no it is not. It does not have any security risks in which you should be concerned with.